# moderncv - Set email and social in latin text

Tags: moderncv, languages, greek

My CV is in greek but I would like the LinkedIn and email to show up in latin text.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic} 

\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\firstname{Όνομα}
\familyname{Επίθετο}
\title{Επάγγελμα}        
\address{Οδός 1}{Πόλη}   
\mobile{1234567891}    
\social[linkedin]{john-doe}
\email{johndoe@gmail.com}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: CV image]

Note: For latin text I use the `\textlatin{}` commmand (which doesn't seem to work in the `\email{}` and `\social{}` commands).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with these redefinitions:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic} 

\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\emaillink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{mailto:#2}{\textlatin{#2}}}%
    {\href{mailto:#2}{\textlatin{#1}}}}

\renewcommand*{\httpslink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{\textlatin{#2}}}%
    {\href{https://#2}{\textlatin{#1}}}}
\makeatother

\firstname{Όνομα}
\familyname{Επίθετο}
\title{Επάγγελμα}        
\address{Οδός 1}{Πόλη}   
\mobile{1234567891}    
\social[linkedin]{john-doe}
\email{johndoe@gmail.com}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]